# Configuration problem in my production server in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, config, production

Well, I have a shared host and I haven't ssh access. The problem is the server structure and symfony estructure...

Server has this estructure

error/
log/
...
web/

and in web dir we can load web application. Symfony structure is..

app/
..
web/

Well the problem is that with my domain, if I try to access I have to put [www.domainname.com/web/](http://www.domainname.com/web/) to access at Symfony project....

1. if I try to copy all web Symfony content to web directory it render first page ok(index.php) but links are wrong because they are [www.domainame.com/moduleName/](http://www.domainame.com/moduleName/)  and this directory does not exist...
2. if I create an .htacces file in web domain dir... when I put [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) it redirects me to web automatic but the other links have [www.domainname.com/web/moduleName/](http://www.domainname.com/web/moduleName/)  in his direction

I want ONLY [www.domainname.com/moduleName/..](http://www.domainname.com/moduleName/..). how I can do it?

### Edit 1

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

### Edit 2

Another problem related:

```
..
/web/
   app/
   ...
   web/
/blog/
```

If I modify this, I will have problems accessing to my /blog/ dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the /web to be removed from the url you need to use an apache module called mod_rewrite. Like so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The docs for this are [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/03-Running-Symfony).

The proper way to set up symfony though is to use a Virtual Host which is pointed at the web folder. This will use the web folder as your root and therefore you won't see it in the url.

Comment: peter it not works well because it redirects me to web server module.. in my .htacces file (i edited post) you can see what works me... but only when i put www.domain.com  the other links are... www.domain.com/web/module  and i want to delete /web/

Comment: i try to do...
$this->setWebDir($this->getRootDir().'/web');
and code you paste but it doesn't work... i have edited my answer.

thanks

Comment: finally i copy the web(symfony) content, to web(server). change projectconfiguration route and it works well with

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess
mod_rewrite

Comment: davidosomething... i have edited my post to show you my .htaccess file.. what i have to modify¿